# Visual Studio Crashing When I Select Text in Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash

I just installed VS 2010 and had no errors, but whenever I'm in the code editor and try to select text, either by CTRL-A, SHIFT-ARROW or click and drag the program crashes.

Here is the debug info:

EventType : clr20r3     P1 : devenv.exe     P2 : 10.0.30319.1     P3 : 4ba1fab3
P4 : uiautomationprovider     P5 : 4.0.0.0     P6 : 4ba1f837     P7 : 3
P8 : 0     P9 : system.dllnotfoundexception

The only mention of it I an find on google is this link, to which I have just posted:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/7e8983f8-48c5-4c6c-acef-c6c128a3baa6

Comment: Are you familiar with WinDbg? Try to run VS under it and you will know what exactly dll it tries to load and failed. You can also make app dump and check it yourself or give it someone who can help. Also you can just try to repair it via setup. I suspect some of VS core dlls not installed correctly

Comment: Also just curious do you installed any clipboard modification or helpers? Or maybe some app which monitors and modifies standard system behaviour. Do you try to unload all other app you usually have in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking some of Nick's advice, when it errored out, I debugged it in Visual Studio.  It gave me "Unable to load DLL 'UIAutomationCore.dll'. The specified module could not be found."  I googled that and arrived at

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564071/vs2010-unhandled-net-exception-after-clicking-in-any-xaml-document

which told me to install

Apparently installing the latest version of the UI Automation API solved the problem.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=cd55456d-9703-42a0-b982-8a8a89ca0aa3&displaylang=en

And that fixed the issue :)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I do not understand why this is not installed with service pack (re-installed Visual Studio 2010 and service packs thrice)?!

Answer (score 1):

The .NET 4.0 install did not go well.  The missing DLL is supposed to be present in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35

Reinstalling .NET 4.0 would be your next move.  But do worry a bit about your machine stability, DLLs don't just disappear or not get installed.

Comment: Tried repairing the .Net 4.0 install.  No luck.  Downloading the standalone installer now to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the defualt behavior for Visual Studio.  The most likely cause of the crash is a 3rd party plugin.  Try disabling any plugin and repeating the scenario.

Comment: Disabled everything but antivirus and removed all addins in VS.  No luck.