# Visual Studio Crashing When I Select Text in Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, exception, crash

I have *exactly* the same problem as this SO poster; [Visual Studio Crashing When I Select Text in Code Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962814/visual-studio-crashing-when-i-select-text-in-code-editor/3962918), except I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate and the fix for bulltorious isn't workable for me on Windows 7.

Event Viewer reports the error as;

```
Fault bucket 1097131459, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 10.0.30319.1
P3: 4ba1fab3
P4: UIAutomationProvider
P5: 4.0.0.0
P6: 4ba1f837
P7: 3
P8: 0
P9: System.DllNotFoundException
P10:
```

I can't select any text in any file type. If I attempt to add or edit *any* code, I crash to desktop. I have done Windows Update and updated the usual drivers just in case. No luck.

I have no add-ins running and I've tried running **devenv /safemode**, with no success.  I know this has something to do with **UIAutomationProvider**, but with no idea how to fix it!

Any ideas?

I did post on Microsoft's Connect, but that was useless: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618754/visual-studio-2010-crash-on-code-view-load

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have the latest updates and SPs for VS2010?

Comment: Thanks for the response Philippe. As far as I can ascertain, yes I do. I have checked Windows Update and I've searched Microsoft for anything particular. I have also reinstalled .NET 4.0, so-far; no dice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-engineering the [Watson dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10/4053325#4053325), it is crashing in MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreProviderApi.RawUiaClientsAreListening.  This is a pinvoked function from UIAutomationCore.dll

You'll need to find out what happened to that DLL.  It is present in c:\windows\system32, mine has a time-stamp of July 13th 2009, 6:27:31 pm CST.

Comment: Hi Hans,  thanks very much for the answer. I have checked my .dll, it is indeed within c:\windows\system32 and it has a time-stamp of July 14th 2009 at 2:16am GMT.  Seems close enough to your .dll for me to assume that our files are the same?

Comment: Yes it is the same.  Start + Run, cmd.exe, OK and type PATH at the command prompt.  Verify that c:\windows\system32 is listed.

Comment: Also run Dumpbin.exe /exports on the file and verify that "UiaClientsAreListening" is present.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I did just this and although it didn't solve the problem directly, it gave me enough clues to send me on my way :)  Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @dooburt do you happen to remember what steps you took to solve the problem? I'm experiencing a very similar issue and looking for fixes.

Comment: @DMGregory cripes, this was a while ago! I think I replaced UIAutomation dll from somewhere and that solved the problem. I realise now how useless this answer is - because it doesn't actually tell the reader what to fix!

Comment: Fix the DLL, like you did, should be obvious.

Comment: I am suspicious this has something to do with Flight Simulator X as well, because that had a problem which relied on replacing the same DLL and could well have been the cause (or solution to this). Bottom line, Hans is right, replace the DLL and the problem will be fixed.